Google API Key - can't use protected member in code, but can in debug session
I'm trying to use Google Address Validation API, using API key authentication, with the following code:
    Const MyApiKey = "(my-api-key)"
    Dim ClientBuilder As New Google.Maps.AddressValidation.V1.AddressValidationClientBuilder
    ClientBuilder.ApiKey = MyApiKey
    Dim Client = ClientBuilder.Build

This code fails to compile with the error message
Error   BC30389 'Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase(Of Google.Maps.AddressValidation.V1.AddressValidationClient).ApiKey' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected'.
If I comment out ClientBuilder.ApiKey = MyApiKey, debug the code, break before ClientBuilder.Build, in the immediate window I can successfully assign ClientBuilder.ApiKey = ApiKey , and it works, i.e. the client successfully validates an address. Why does it work in debug session but does not compile? How to make it compile?

It doesn't compile because you cannot access protected members from outside the class or its inheritors. That's basic programming principles. The debugger probably uses Reflection to set it. It wouldn't follow the usual rules in order to allow you to change any state you want for testing purposes. You're going to have to find out how to get the API key in some other way. Presumably there is a standard for that but I've never used that type and a quick search didn't reveal anything, so you'll have to look a bit deeper.
